# How can I check a enum using an if statement in swift?

Tags: swift, if-statement, enums, operators

Today I was writing an app that needs to correct some `Double`s to a number of significant figures/digits (sig fig). The user can sets the no. of sig fig to convert to. I store this piece of information in `NSUserDefaults`.

I created an enum to represent these settings because I want to make my code more readable, instead of just plain old integers. Here is the enum:

```
enum SigFigOptions{
    case No
    case Yes(Int)
}
```

If it is `.No`, the numbers will be exact. If it is `.Yes`, the numbers will be corrected. And the number of sig fig is stored in the associated value.

I then created a method inside the enum called `correctTo`.

```
func correctTo (i: Double) -> Double {
    if self == .No {

    }
}
```

When I was writing this, I saw that there was a syntax error, saying that it is ambiguous. So I changed it to:

```
if self == SigFigOptions.No
```

But then it says that `==` cannot be used on two `SigFigOptions` types.

I really don't understand! I know that I can use a `switch` to do this. But I think `switch` should be used when there are lots of cases. In this kind of situation, I think it's better to use an if statement to enhance readability. But I just can't compare them!

Can you tell me how to compare enums using if statement?

Oh by the way, if you know the algorithm to correct a number to a certain sig fig. Please kindly show it to me.

Comment: I guess you could implement `Equatable`, but that won't do much for readability. Also, you'd probably use matching to extract the value if the option is `Yes`, so having an if and a switch instead of two cases in the same switch may not buy you much.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a pattern binding: `if case .No = self { ... }`